# Problem with ZTE MF193A usb modem in 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, usb, usb-modem, modem, zte

Recently I've bought a zte mf 193a data card. It came with the zte driver and application software for windows,linux and mac. I am able to use it in windows but I got trouble in ubuntu(12.04LTS).

There is an install.sh script to install the application software.
After running the install.sh script, it proceeds installation with following line:

```
ls: can't access /usr/share/applications/desktop.*.cache: No such file or directory
```

After processing few more it says that installation is successful , press any key to continue.

After pressing a key pc gets stuck and hangs forever after throwing the following lines:

```
Testability plugin /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/473/gcc/plugins/testability/testability.so load failed with error: The shared library was not found.
Qobject::connect: can't connect (null): clicked to .......
```

and more ....

Then i have to press and hold the power button to shutdown the pc. After booting up the pc gets stuck again within few minutes if the modem is plugged in. The application can run alone without detecting the modem.

I have rebooted and tried several times but no luck. please help me.

Terminal output is similar as follows:

```
..................................................
..................................................
Grameenphone_Internet/Skin/mainminimizeclicked.png
Grameenphone_Internet/Skin/mainminimizehover.png
Grameenphone_Internet/Skin/mainmsgbutton.png
Grameenphone_Internet/Skin/MainMsgButton_1.png
Grameenphone_Internet/Skin/MainMsgButton_2.png
Grameenphone_Internet/Skin/MainMsgButton_3.png
Grameenphone_Internet/Skin/MainMsgButton_4.png
.............................................
.......................................
Grameenphone_Internet/UpdateCfg.ini
Grameenphone_Internet/UpdateInfo.xml
Grameenphone_Internet/UUDb
Grameenphone_Internet/usr/share/applications/
Grameenphone_Internet/usr/share/pixmaps/
Grameenphone_Internet/usr/share/
Grameenphone_Internet/usr/lib/
Grameenphone_Internet/plugins/codecs/
Grameenphone_Internet/plugins/imageformats/
Grameenphone_Internet/Help/English/
Grameenphone_Internet/Config/
Grameenphone_Internet/usr/
Grameenphone_Internet/plugins/
Grameenphone_Internet/Help/
Grameenphone_Internet/bin/
Grameenphone_Internet/driver/
Grameenphone_Internet/scripts/
Grameenphone_Internet/sqldrivers/
Grameenphone_Internet/wirelessconfig/
Grameenphone_Internet/pppd/
Grameenphone_Internet/Data/
Grameenphone_Internet/Image/
Grameenphone_Internet/qss/
Grameenphone_Internet/Skin/
Grameenphone_Internet/Sound/
Grameenphone_Internet/userdata/
Grameenphone_Internet/Language/
Grameenphone_Internet/UiFile/
Grameenphone_Internet/
ls: cannot access /usr/share/applications/desktop.*.cache: No such file or directory
******Begin to /opt/Grameenphone_Internet/driver
this is linux driver installtion
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-56-generic-pae/build M=/tmp/ZTE_driver_install_V3.26 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-56-generic-pae'
  CC [M]  /tmp/ZTE_driver_install_V3.26/zte.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/ZTE_driver_install_V3.26/zte.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/ZTE_driver_install_V3.26/zte.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-56-generic-pae'
this  is customized kernel ,kernel version is: 3.2.0-56-generic-pae
enter customize_driver_install function
disselfirefox.pp driver_install.run driver_uninstall.sh nm.pp se End to /opt/Grameenphone_Internet/driver
udevadm is exist!
install completed!!!
....After setup, you will find the Grameenphone Internet in "Applications->Internet->Grameenphone Internet". Click the Grameenphone Internet and the application will run
press any key to continue....  Testability plugin /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/473/gcc/plugins/testability/libtestability.so load failed with error:The shared library was not found.
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormConnect_Laos_Star::slotToConnectLogForm()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormConnect_Laos_Star::slotChangeApn()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormMain_Laos_Star::slotMainMenu()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormMain_Laos_Star::slotSettingButtonClicked()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormMain_Laos_Star::slotStkButtonClicked()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormMain_Laos_Star::slotHelpButtonClicked()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormMain_Laos_Star::slotVoiceButtonClicked()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormMain_Laos_Star::slotVoiceRecordButtonClicked()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormMain_Laos_Star::slotHomeButtonClicked()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormMain_Laos_Star::slotNewReciveSMSClicked()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormMain_Laos_Star::slotMissedCallSignClicked()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormMain_Laos_Star::slotCallingSignClicked()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormMain_Laos_Star::slotMissedCallSignClicked()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormMain_Laos_Star::slotShowV4v6Info()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormMain_Laos_Star::slotClickMainButtonActiveSIM()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormMain_Laos_Star::slotClickMainButtonRefill()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormInputPin::slotInputPinCancel()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormInputPuk::slotInputPukCancel()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormSmsBox_Laos_Star::slotReadButtonClicked()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormSmsBox_Laos_Star::slotSaveButtonClicked()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormSmsBox_Laos_Star::slotToSmsMainForm()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormSmsBox_Laos_Star::slotToCall()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormSmsChat::slotToNewSmsForm()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked (bool) to UUFormSmsChat::slotSelectAllAction(bool)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormSmsChat::slotDeleteChatRecord()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormSmsChat::slotDeleteSearchContentButtonClicked()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormSmsChat::slotShowCommonToolMenu()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::textChanged(QString) to UUFormSmsChat::slotSearchSmsPcContent()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::textChanged(QString) to UUSmsRecordListDelegate::slotSetSearchKey(const QString&)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::doubleClicked(QModelIndex) to UUFormSmsChat::slotSearchSmsItemRead(const QModelIndex &)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormSmsChatSession::slotDeleteSelectedSms()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::stateChanged(int) to UUFormSmsChatSession::slotSelectAllAction(int)
QString::arg: Argument missing: "Info:" , 0 
QString::arg: Argument missing: "Info:" , 0 
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormSmsRead::slotSaveNumber()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormSmsRead::slotForwardMessage()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormSmsRead::slotReplyMessage()
Designer: An error has occurred while reading the UI file at line 1, column 0: Premature end of document.
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::clicked() to UUFormSmsCapacity::slotSmsCapacityBack()
begin bind slotSystermSleeping(), slotSystermResuming(), UUPowerStateListener::startListen_Linux() 
end bind slotSystermSleeping(), slotSystermResuming(), UUPowerStateListener::startListen_Linux()
```

Comment: When I type **apt-file search "libtestability.so"**, I am not getting anything.

Comment: Just wait a bit longer, the modem will work.

Answer (score 0):

### I connect it in Ubuntu 14.04LTS

1. Connect the modem with USB and it will detect it as a CD-Rom
2. Explore the CD-Rom and get 3 folders, one of them is Linux
3. Explore Linux folder and copy `PCL_Bengal_GP.tar.gz` and paste it in `Home` folder.
4. Now extract it in `Home` folder
5. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open `Terminal`
6. Now Write the following command and press Enter

   ```
   cd PCL_Bengal_GP
   ```
7. Then Write the following command and press Enter

   ```
   sudo bash install.sh
   ```
8. Then wait to open GUI modem's menu and connect
9. After connecting close Terminal

Comment: Yes, you are right. I know that it works with Ubuntu 14.04LTS, but I need it in Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the first warning is not a severe one but the second one related to shared library is. You can manually download the package containing the shared library and then delete all the files related to the installation and then try to install again. To do so run the following commands successively:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-file search "libtestability.so"
```

This would give you the package that contains `libtestability.so`. Install the package manually by `sudo apt-get install "PackageName"` and then try to install again after removing all installation files.

Although this is skewed solution but this should solve the issue as far as the second warning is concerned.

**N.B:** `apt-file` will eat some space as it will populate `/var/cacahe/apt/apt-file` with list of files of packages from all repos mentioned in sources.list.

---

You can also do the same thing by doing an online search on

http://packages.ubuntu.com/

for the file and get the package containing the file and then install.

---

** Note that, as expected, if there is no package in the repositories containing the searched file, then this method will not work and you need to sort out the package by yourself using some other way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in the meantime i've been updated to 14.04, i'll try it to other machine of 12.04

Comment: Have you tested this method yourself? It seems no package provides the file `libtestability.so`

Comment: @AnwarShah This was a generalization..clarified..